# yup validation using matches

Tags: reactjs, yup

I want validate a form using yup , the issue is : although the field is not required when I post the form I get an error : only digits . the field is considered as required.

`yup.string().matches(/^[0-9 ]+$/,'only digits').min(10, 'exactly 10 digits').max(10, 'exactly 10 digits')`

even when I add .notRequired() it doesn't work

any help please

Comment: Would you mind share your code?

Comment: it's hard to help with so little information but if all you want is a number, why not use yup.number() ?